# Regex for word excluding lines that have another word

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep

Input:

```
hello world.
This is hello world.
Another hello world.
New hello world.
```

Now search for all occurrences of `hello` excluding lines that contain `This`

Search Output:

```
hello world
Another hello world
New hello world.
```

Now replace all those `hello` with `hell`

Replace Output:

```
hell world.
This is hello world.
Another hell world.
New hell world.
```

Comment: I don't think grep can do replacement...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk` to do this

```
awk '/hello/ && !/This/ {gsub(/hello/,"hell")}8' file
hell world.
This is hello world.
Another hell world.
New hell world.
```

Comment: @nhahtdh  It was just an typo, no need to give negative after 10 seconds.

Comment: I will do so on a wrong answer. As long as it is corrected, I'll remove my downvote. (Well, your current downvote is not mine). Btw, this only works on nawk and gawk, as far as I can see from http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Awk.html#uh-40

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks, but wait some seconds next time before you down vote :)  This should work with nearly all `awk`  `gsub` is a standard function.  `sub` could also be used, but would only replace one `hello` in every line.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` does not do replacement, so you need to use a different tool. [*Jotne*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21378314/1331399) has shown how to do it with `awk`, here is how to do it with `sed`:

```
sed -e '/This/b' -e '/hello/ s/hello/hell/' file
```

Output:

```
hell world.
This is hello world.
Another hell world.
New hell world.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pi -e 's/hello/hell/g if(/hello/ && $_!~/This/)' your_file
```

More simpler version:

```
perl -pi -e 's/hello/hell/g unless(/This/)' your_file
```

Tested Below:

```
> cat temp
hello world.
This is hello world.
Another hello world.
New hello world.
> perl -pe 's/hello/hell/g unless(/This/)' temp
hell world.
This is hello world.
Another hell world.
New hell world.
>
```

Answer (score 1):

why not simply do this:

```
sed '/This/!s/hello/hell/g'
```

or I misunderstood the requirement? it gives:

```
hell world.
This is hello world.
Another hell world.
New hell world.
```

Comment: could be funny with a echo "helloo work" :-). Your sed is the most efficient for this request